# Trying to use if statements to run wget

Tags: shell, if-statement, wget

I am trying to setup a script that looks at the current date and hour then puts it into the format yyyymmdd + 2 digits. An example would be 2015041506. The hour should be based on the 24-hour clock.

The script would then echo the date and then run wget.

```
#!/bin/sh

#
# variables
#

basedir1="http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/hur/prod/hur."
#basedir2="http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/hur/prod/hwrf."
date=`date +"%Y%m%d"`
date2=`date +"%Y%m%d" -d "yesterday"`
hour=`date +%H`

#
# main
#


if [ $hour = "7" ]
then
datetime=`${date}06`
echo ${datetime}
url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1

elif [ $hour = "13" ]
then
datetime=`${date}12`
echo ${datetime}
url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1

elif [ $hour = "19" ]
then
datetime=`${date}18`
echo ${datetime}
url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1

elif [ $hour = "1" ]
then
datetime=`${date2}00`
echo ${datetime}
url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1
fi
```

The script does not appear to be working.

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: The script does not seem to work correctly. It is not echoing the info.

Comment: learn to use the preferred  $( ... ) instead of the back-tick method ` ... `   and multi way else-if are better put in a case statement.  example to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `if [ $hour == "07" ]` (note the double `=`)

Answer (score 1):

```
case $hour in
13)
    datetime=`${date}12`
    echo ${datetime}
    url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
    wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1
    ;;
19)
    datetime=`${date}18`
    echo ${datetime}
    url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
    wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1
1) 
    datetime=`${date2}00`
    echo ${datetime}
    url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
    wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P     /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1
    ;;
*)
    datetime=`${date}06`
    echo ${datetime}
    url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
    wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1
    ;;
esac
```

then i'd look at the wget commands, since each of the first three lines is quite similar, at least in terms of the 'datetime' assignment.  (i'm too lazy to do that work for you.  i.e. is there *any* thing different about them than the assignment of "datetime".

if not, then factor that part out  e.g. your whole thing *might* (?) look like this:

```
case $hour in
13) dh=12;;
19) dh=18;;
1)  dh=06;;
*)  dh=00;;
esac

    datetime=$(date)$dh
    echo ${datetime}
    url1="${basedir1}${datetime}/"
    wget -r -l1 --no-parent -e robots=off -R 'index.*' -A '*.grib.*.grib2' -P /awips2/edex/data/manual/ $url1
```

Comment: Datetime is the only difference with the first three lines.

Comment: Would I need to break it down further even using a case statement? If the $hour is 1, use $date2. If the $hour is greater than 1, use $date1.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace :

```
datetime=`${date}06`
```

with

```
datetime="${date}06"
```

And concerning :

```
if [ $hour = "7" ]
```

make sure it is

```
if [ $hour = "07" ]
```